# How to get index inside ng-repeat with file input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of records which I upload using file input. My purpose is to upload a file in a row when '+' is clicked and remove the file when 'x' is clicked.

My issue is, whenever I upload one file in one record, all other records are also get updated by the same file. I'm sure that I'm missing to use the `$index` logic here. I'm already passing `this` with `onchange` event of file input. How can I pass `$index` along with that?

```html
<div ng-repeat="itemList in FilesToShow track by $index">
    <div style="width: 90%; display: inline-block;">{{itemList.FileName}}</div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;display: inline-block;"
         ng-click="removefile(itemList)">x</div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;display: inline-block;"
         ng-focus="$parent.focused = true" ng-if="FilesToShow.length==0">+</div>
</div>
<input ng-if="focused" ng-disabled="FilesToShow.length==1" type="file"
       id="fileId" value="Browse..." name="file"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFileDetails(this)" />
```

```js
$scope.FilesToShow = [];
$scope.getFileDetails = function(hisLstFile) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    var Historyvalue = {
      FileName: hisLstFile.files[0].name,
      IsFileDeleted: false,
      DownloadPath: null,
      Id: null
    };
    $scope.FilesToShow.push(Historyvalue);
  });
}
```

Comment: use $index inside of the ng-repeat scope

Comment: @DarshanDave, How to use is my question :)

Comment: no, but i suggested you base on my knowledge

Comment: have you  tried ?

Comment: I think you should look at some tutorials on using angularjs as well as looking in to maybe some general programming tutorials. This is very poorly written code. To fix this would essentially require an entire re-write, which I don't think many people on SO will be willing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `$index` as an argument in the function.
Just make sure that it's in the `ng-repeat` scope.
Like:

```
onchange="myFunction(this, $index)";
```

good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried that and got the error message `$index` is undefined. I double checked whether its inside `ng-repeat` scope!